# Angular orderby with JSON-hyphen

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a JSON-file with hyphen in one attribute. I want to sort JSON-data with that attribute using ng-click.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxooMv

```
<a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='square-miles'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
```

does not work and neither does

```
<a href="#" ng-click="orderByField=['square-miles']; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
```

What's the syntax i should use in order for it to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orderBy` uses the `$parse` service internally which will parse your property as the expression:

```
square - miles
```

To get around this you can instead pass your own getter function like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="state in data.states.state|orderBy:orderBy(orderByField):reverseSort">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.orderBy = function(property) {
  return function(item) {
    return item[property];
  };
};
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoZLw

Comment: Your suggestion works like a charm on your demo. However when i added some more JSON-data it appears to sort data based on square-miles randomly.. 
Have a look
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxooMv

Comment: That is an unrelated issue. They are sorted in that order since the values of square-miles are strings. I assume you were expecting a natural sort order: blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order

Comment: If you set one of the populations to `8888888888` and use the default orderBy you will notice the same behavior (it will not be on top): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JobOEJ

Comment: Here is an example that turns them into numbers instead (which will result in a natural sort order): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByQmpM

Comment: Ah yes, natural sort order, that's what i was looking for! Thank you very much!